# iterate echo total number

Tags: php

How could I echo the last number? it should be 9.

```
$i = 0;
while($i != 10){
    echo $i;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code **exactly**?

Comment: What is your code doing, and how is that different from what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to echo just the last number?

```
$i=$j=0;
while($i!=10){
    $j=$i++;
}
echo $j;
```

Although this is a very bad way to do that, I'm only showing it because I believe you're doing something completely different with that code

Comment: That will echo `10` as the number gets increased the last time when it is `9`

Answer (score 1):

```
if {$i = 9) {
echo "$i"; }
```

This should work, if you want you could have an array store variables, and then base the output on user input.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch the last iteration, then take away the loops condition and handle it yourself:

```
while (true) {

    ...

    if (++$i == 9) {
        echo $i;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you bark at the break, then resort to a condition flag `$last = $i == 9;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the condition at the end, you prevent that `$i` gets updated when it shouldn´t anymore.

```
$i = 0;
do {
    $i++;
} while ($i != 10);
echo $i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do the following:

```
echo 9;
```

If the last number is variable, you could do the following:

```
echo $last_number - 1;
```

If there's some weird requirement where you need to do a loop, and you really do need it to loop over all the other numbers before finally echoing the penultimate number, you could just check it every single iteration:

```
$i = 0;
$penult = $last_number - 1;
while ($i !== $last_number) {
    if ($i === $penult) {
        echo $i;
    }
    $i += 1;
}
```

...Or you could use `continue`:

```
$i = 0;
$penult = $last_number - 1;
while ($i !== $last_number) {
    if ($i !== $penult) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $i;
}
```